# i18n Switch Locale once after the app loads

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular7, angular-i18n

For a multi-language site, I am using the below technique to dynamically switch the language in the app. Is this the proper way?

Sometimes, page loads end up with `not-found` and even goes back to the login page.

**main.ts**

```
declare const require;
var translations = require(`raw-loader!./locale/messages.xlf`);

switch(localStorage.getItem("lang"))
{
  case("ta"):
  {
    translations = require(`raw-loader!./locale/messages.ta.xlf`);
    break;
  }
  case("fr"):
  {
    translations = require(`raw-loader!./locale/messages.fr.xlf`);
    break;
  }
  default:
      translations = 'en';
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {

  providers: [
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations},
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf'},
  ]

})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**app.module.ts**

```
var locale = localStorage.getItem("lang")

if (!locale) locale = "en"


providers: [

    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: locale },
    { provide: "BASE_API_URL", useValue: environment.baseUrl},
  ]
```

and in the settings page, the language is selected and redirected back to the home page.

```
<mat-select [formControl]="language">
   <mat-option value="ta">Tamil</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="en">English</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="fr">French</mat-option>
</mat-select>

localStorage.setItem('lang', formValue.language)
//this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload'
this.router.navigate(['/home'])
```

Comment: You can't change the locale without reloading the app (a different app, actually), since it's provided when the module is configured. And you can't change the translations too, since they're hardcoded by the AOT compiler in the compiled templates.

Comment: But the above approach the messages are translated and viewed accordingly but I am facing the issues as in the post. And reloading the app, could you describe it please?

Comment: Try it with a production build, and you'll see. Or just read the official guide: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#internationalization-i18n

Comment: That means, can't we switch the language dynamically once the app loads?

Comment: No, you can't. You need to reload a different app (i.e. the same app, but built for a different language). In the future, we should be able to use a single bundle for all the languages, but will still have to reload the app.

Comment: Ok, that meant I need to have multiple apps built for each language and when on switching language I need to point the url to that app?